# swift 3 uiview animate only showing last two animations

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

Trying to get the background colours of my popup UIView to change between 4 colours and then loop back and repeat. For the code below, only the last two colours are appearing, the first two are skipping, I've tried everything I can think of, any idea what I'm missing?

```
     UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse], animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }, completion: nil)
```

Updated code:

```
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 12, delay: 1, options:
                [UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction,
                 UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat,
                 UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse],
                                       animations: {
                                        self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                                        self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                                        self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                                        self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }, completion:nil )
```

Update 2: Individual animation block:

```
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0, options:
       [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, 
        UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse, 
       .allowUserInteraction], 
       animations: { (BOOL) -> Void in

                self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }) { (Bool) -> Void in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                        self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                            self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                        }, completion:nil)
                    })
                })
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to exactly but the result of your code will change background color to red. In most time you will not see other colors. Changing color in animation block doesn't animate color change.

Comment: I want  it to repeat through the colours one by one . I can extend the duration but that still just shows me grey and red

Comment: You have to put each color change in separate animation block which will be in the completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `backgroundColor` is not animatable.  But if it *was*, or if you wanted to animate something that *is* animatable, the better way to cycle through multiple animations would be to use key frame animation, like so:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 12, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.popupView.backgroundColor = .black
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.25, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.popupView.backgroundColor = .green
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.popupView.backgroundColor = .gray
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.75, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.popupView.backgroundColor = .red
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

In this case I set the `relativeDuration` for each keyFrame to be 0.25 (1/4) of the total animation time, and set the `relativeStartTime` to be beginning, 1/4, 1/2, and 3/4 of the way through the total duration.

Again, to reiterate, that is not an animatable property, but this is an effective way to chain animations together.

It also *is* possible to animate color change by using `transition` instead of `animate`, though you can't do keyFrame transition.  You could chain these together by using the completions, and when you get to the end you'd have to start the animation over again by calling some wrapper function or something similar:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.popupView, duration: 3, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    self.popupView.backgroundColor = .black
}, completion: { (finished) in
    UIView.transition(with: self.popupView, duration: 3, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        self.popupView.backgroundColor = .green
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        UIView.transition(with: self.popupView, duration: 3, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.popupView.backgroundColor = .gray
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            UIView.transition(with: self.popupView, duration: 3, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                self.popupView.backgroundColor = .red
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                //Start the chain over again
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Actually so far the first option seems to have done the trick thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, color change in animation block will not animate color change. However if you want to just change color, it might be okay to use animation block.

To get a result you want with animation block the code should look like below.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 12, delay: 1, options:
            [.allowUserInteraction, .repeat, .autoreverse],
                                   animations: {
                                    self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        }, completion:{ competed in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 12, delay: 1, options:
            [.allowUserInteraction, .repeat, .autoreverse],
                                   animations: {
                                    self.popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }, completion: .... )
```

If you want to just change background color every N seconds, you better use timer.

**UDATE**

Here's an example of using timer.

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var timer: Timer?
    let colors: [UIColor] = [.white, .black, .red, .magenta]
    var idx: Int = 0

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 5,
                      target: self,
                      selector: #selector(changeColor),
                      userInfo: nil,
                      repeats: true)
    }

    @objc
    func changeColor() {
        view.backgroundColor = colors[idx]
        idx = (idx + 1) % colors.count
    }
}
```

Using timer will make your code simpler.

Comment: The issue with this and the the update 2 in my post is the code only goes as fast as changing to black and back. I figured it had something to do with he autoreverse or repeat and have swapped each of them out and in but still can't get it to loop.

Comment: What you really want to is looping, you have to use `Timer`. I'll add example in a min.

Comment: Thanks, the keyframes option from creeperspeak worked for me so sticking with that for now, if it fails for whatever reason, I will swap to the timer option.